# Some questions on 'Almost All Subgroups of a Lie Group Are Free'

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, free-groups

I am currently reading this paper:http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869371901074/1-s2.0-0021869371901074-main.pdf?_tid=dbe2268a-086f-11e5-b2dc-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1433171402_aab9d149d19998874901ebf011ab0a5f

And it is not going too well for me.

First of all, what is the map $w$ he defined at the start. I know it should be some sort of way of multiplying things(I think), but this map depends on the word.

Secondly, how can one show for any
analytic mapping from a connected analytic manifold $M$ to an analytic
manifold $N$, the inverse image of a point in $N$ is either the whole of M or has
measure zero in $M$.

Thirdly, what does no relation $w$ is satisfied identically on $G$ mean?

Finally, can someone give me a concrete example of this? (Say $GL(2,Z)$, and $n=2$)

I am only a second year maths undergraduate. I only know basic definitions on Haar measure and Lie group.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $w$ is defined by the word $w$ as follows. Suppose you have a word in, say, $2$ generators, e.g. $w=aba^2b^3$. This defines an analytic mapping $w\colon G^2\rightarrow G$ by $(a,b)\mapsto aba^2b^3$.

Secondly, this is easily proved by taking $M$ to be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and using induction on $m$, and Fubini’s theorem. OK, here you have to fill in some details.

Thirdly, $w\equiv 1$ is satisfied identically in $G$ means $aba^2b^3=1$ for all $a,b$ in our example.

Finally, did you study free groups already ? I think, you should do this first.

Comment: thank you very much for the fast respond. This helped a lot. Yes, I did some reading on free groups first then it led me to this paper. This is the first time I see measure theory and group theory used together. I was going to ask why $G$ need to be non-solvable, but i guess otherwise you cant find a free group of rank 2 in $G$. I am still a bit confused about the second question, is fubini's theorm this: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem?

Comment: opps, forgot to tag